# How can I improve my ear for intonation?

Tags: practice, tuning, ear-training, trombone

I play tenor trombone, possibly switching to bass trombone. I need to improve my ear for tuning and noticing whether or not I am either sharp or flat. How can I practice in this area?

Answer (score 3):

Play duets, either with another person, or with a recording of yourself or your teacher or an advanced student.  Play in wind ensembles.  Play in chamber ensembles.  Attend concerts and recitals.  Get a used sightsinging book.  Sing your pieces -- it's okay if your voice isn't drop-dead gorgeous.

Comment: I think this is a great answer that could be improved by adding “and learn to sing”

Comment: 'Play duets with another person' - who you *know* will only play exactly in tune.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Get a tuner — an app will suffice — that displays whether you are sharp or flat. You'll also want a tone generator, which is easy to find online ([here's one I use](https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/)).

Run the tone generator through an ear bud so the tuner doesn't pick it up. Then set both the tone generator and the tuner to a pitch you'd like to practice tuning.

Start the tone playing, then play your trombone, and the tuner will tell you which direction you need to adjust, sharp or flat.

Once you're comfortable, start doing the exercise with your eyes closed, and try to hear whether you're sharp or flat, then use the tuner to check yourself.

Comment: Honest question… can you actually train pitch recognition, or is it just innate ability + practise [I guess I ought to ask that as a proper question or google it… but whilst you're here… ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin To the best of my understanding and experience, pitch recognition cannot be taught/learned; it's innate. However, pitch matching and tuning an instrument accurately can definitely be taught and learned.

Comment: Ah, OK, cool, thanks. I think I grok the distinction. However I actually learned it, it was now so long ago I haven't a clue how I did it ;))

Comment: A lot of best understanding that something can’t be learned or can’t be learned after some specific age is just wrong.

Comment: @ojs Rather than a vague swipe at a sincere attempt to answer a question, one that acknowledges the limits of the answerer, it would be helpful if you posted some evidence that absolute pitch can be successfully taught.

Comment: @Aaron first it was playing in tune and now it needs to be absolute pitch? If I try to answer, you'll just shift the goalposts again. Can you first define what kind of pitch recognition you mean, why any less isn't enough for playing in tune and proof that it can't be taught? "My teacher told so" or "I read it in the same textbook that said brain cells don't regenerate" is not enough.

Comment: @ojs The "to the best of my understanding" comment was in relation to absolute pitch, which is what Tetsujin asked about. The goalposts have not moved.

Comment: @Aaron honestly I don’t see absolute pitch mentioned there. Wouldn’t be the first time he deletes comments, though. So, do you have some evidence it can’t be taught?

Comment: @ojs "Pitch recognition", in the context of the discussion, means "absolute pitch".

Comment: "Get a tuner — an app will suffice — that displays whether you are sharp or flat": tuners aren't very helpful for ensemble tuning.  The exercise suggested here is probably helpful to learn pitch matching, which is an important skill, but brass ensembles typically do not employ equal temperament.  If everyone in the group matches the note prescribed by the tuner, it doesn't sound particularly good.  After mastering the exercise here, a player might want to modify it by playing some other pitch than the generated tone -- and not necessarily tuning them to ET.

Comment: @Aaron - it seems to have gone astray (while my computer's provider's been off line!) but the question isn't about hearing a note and identifying it  (ah, that's C#) but *matching* pitches - singing or playing in tune. AP didn't feature!

Comment: @Tim Tetsujin asked a question about AP — using the term "pitch recognition" — in the comments.

Comment: @Aaron - maybe that just meant recognising a pitch to be able to sing that same pitch? It's not too clear. (To me). Bit like recognising someone's face, but not being able to put a name to it.

Comment: @Tim Since my answer to Tetsujin was satisfactory, you'd have to clarify with Tetsujin.